# Overloading delete operator to delete something allocated in library

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-libraries

I'm using framework which has a class Register, into which I'm able to register instances of A.

```
Register r;
A * a1 = new A();
r->register(a1);
A * a2 = new A();
r->register(a2);
```

Register will take ownership and deletes all registered `A`s when going out of scope.

I want to modify `A`s behaviour in shared library (.so in my case), so, I'm gonna do something like this (in the library):

```
class B : public A {
    ...
}

B * get_customized_a() {
    return new B();
}
```

And then in main program

```
Register r;
A * a1 = get_customized_a();
r->register(a1);
```

but now `a1` will be deleted in main program, not in the library! Which from I understud is a big no-no.

So how to solve this?

---

I've come up with two solution:

1) Use A and customize it by stand-alone function

in plugin:

```
void customize_a(A * a) { ... }
```

in main program:

```
Register r;
A * a1 = new A();
customize_a(a1);
r->register(a1);
```

I must say I don't like it that much :/

2) Overload delete operator for class B

in plugin

```
class B : public A {
    ...
    static void operator delete(void * ptr) {
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
}
```

in main program:

```
Register r;
A * a1 = get_customized_a();
r->register(a1);
```

However, I never overloaded `operator delete` before so I'm not sure if this will even work (as intended).

3) Is there any approach I missed? Is there a better solution?

Thank you all.

Comment: Does `A` have a virtual dtor? Also, on which platform are you?

Comment: No, if I'm reading source correctly, `A` doesn't have virtual dtor. Platform is Linux, AMD64

Comment: If it's Linux, you really don't have to take any special care about module-boundaries. Deleting through a base-type without virtual dtor stays UB though.

Comment: Sooo... on linux I can safely in main program delete something allocated in shared library? Is this in-practice-it-works kind of behaviour, or it does work always?

Comment: And any thoughts how to handle the absence of virtual dtor ? :/

Comment: @Paladin - `And any thoughts how to handle the absence of virtual dtor?`  Add one to the base class.

Comment: Of course it is only it works by default, and you can break it if you want. If you override global `new` and `delete`, take a look at the final so/executable: Does it really properly export them (noticed a bug lately: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25922895)? Regarding the missing virtual on the dtor, fix your code. Or play roulette.

Comment: @Deduplicator @PaulMcKenzie that's the problem, `A` is not my code :/ I cannot just change function signature :/ So basically I'm screwed? :D

Comment: You are screwed, though how much ... If you don't add any members in the derived class, and don't add a custom dtor, it should work even though it's UB. No guarantees there.

Comment: @Paladin - Well, if the class doesn't have a virtual destructor, then maybe it was never meant to be derived from.  Does `A` have any virtual functions?  If so, then immediately contact the author to add a virtual destructor.  That amounts IMO to a bug, even though the code will compile.  If there are no virtual functions, then again, the class was probably not designed to be derived from.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, it does have virtual functions. Plus inheriting from it is recommended way to use it according to documentation. I'll ask why dtor is not virtual.

Comment: @Paladin - If what you say is true, then honestly, it is an oversight by the author.  The class should have a virtual destructor, otherwise it truly can't be used polymorphically without at some point invoking UB.  You certainly can't use it if you're creating derived objects dynamically, but destroying the objects using a pointer to the base class.

Comment: @Paladin - Just to make sure, is `A` derived from any other class?  If so, does the class that `A` is derived from have a virtual destructor?  In other words, is there any virtual destructor defined in any parent class of `A`?

Comment: Oh, stupid me :/ I didn't check that. Yes, `A`'s base does have virtual dtor. So I can just let the `Register` delete it even when it was allocated in shared library and it should work just fine on linux.. Thank you sirs :)