# Valgrind reporting Mismatched free() / delete / delete []

Tags: c++, gcc, valgrind, new-operator, gcc6

I'm writing a library that will operate on multiple systems (some of which do not have `malloc` or a stdlib). In my stdlib (different lib), I am overriding the `new` and `delete` operators to make generic calls to functions (this example doesn't have these functions). Each system will override these generic calls to their respective memory allocation devices.

The issue is when I attempt to do this. Here is some stripped down example code to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <cstdlib>

void* operator new(unsigned long size) {
        return std::malloc(size); // would normally call an intermediate function which would be overridden by the system
}

void operator delete(void* object) {
        std::free(object); // would normally call an intermediate function which would be overridden by the system
}
void operator delete(void* object, unsigned long size) {
        std::free(object); // would normally call an intermediate function which would be overridden by the system
}

class MyClass {

};

int main() {
    MyClass* myClass = new MyClass();
    delete myClass;
}
```

When I build it with plain `gcc-6` (no args) and run with `valgrind` (no args), I get this error:

```
==11219== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==11219==    at 0x4C2DD6B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11219==    by 0x108730: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /home/chris13524/tmp/test.o)
==11219==    by 0x10875A: main (in /home/chris13524/tmp/test.o)
==11219==  Address 0x5200040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 alloc'd
==11219==    at 0x4C2D1AF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11219==    by 0x108745: main (in /home/chris13524/tmp/test.o)
```

It appears the `delete` operator is working correctly, but Valgrind is overriding my overridden `new` operator. Any idea how to fix this?

Removing the intermediate functions is not an option as I have other code in there.

Example of how it works on my real program (again, not shown in my example):

```
new => create => <intermediate code> => createImpl => malloc
create => <intermediate code> => createImpl => malloc
```

I'm using gcc v6.2.0, valgrind v3.12.0, and Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: I'm not such a big C++ guy, but your question caught my eye.  I observe that the signature of your operator function does not match the standard signature you seem to be trying to override: `void* operator new  ( std::size_t count )`.  The argument type differs, or at least might do, depending on what `std::size_t` resolves to.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Changing the type does not fix the issue. Either way, this would not be an option as some systems do not have `std::size_t`.

Comment: Double check that your overloaded operators are actually being called (write something to output eg.). It looks like it called the built-in `operator new`, but your replacement `operator delete`, which is clearly a mismatch. Try this both with and without valgrind (to determine if valgrind is the culprit). Also, mentioning your compiler and version, as well as the valgrind version (and your platform) might help.

Comment: Your example fails to reproduce the error for me on gcc 4.8.2 with valgrind 3.9.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker It's only calling `delete(void* object, unsigned long size)`

Comment: @ComicSansMS Same, was unable to reproduce on v5 either. I'm using gcc v6 to get this.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Without Valgrind, it calls both `new` and `delete(2xargs)`.

Comment: Here's a similar issue, but with Clang instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922895/clang-link-time-optimization-with-replaced-operator-new-causes-mismatched-free

Comment: It seems that if I explicitly call the first delete: `operator delete (myClass)`, Valgrind will now override both of my functions (producing no output).

Comment: See this bug I just created: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=372347

Comment: Any updates? having the same problem here..

Comment: @rcmgleite It hasn't been patched yet afaik, comment on the bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Paul Floyd, this bug has been fixed in commit [6ef6f738a](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=valgrind.git;a=commit;h=6ef6f738a). See bug report [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=372347).

However, this fix hasn't been released yet (as of June 2018), and will likely take longer to show up in distributions. If you need this fix now, I suggest building from [source](http://valgrind.org/downloads/repository.html).